# Java: do something x percent of the time

Tags: java

I need a few lines of Java code that run a command x percent of the time at random.

psuedocode:

```
boolean x = true 10% of cases.

if(x){
  System.out.println("you got lucky");
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If by *time* you mean *times that the code is being executed*, so that you want something, inside a code block, that is executed 10% of the times the whole block is executed you can just do something like:

```
Random r = new Random();

...
void yourFunction()
{
  float chance = r.nextFloat();

  if (chance <= 0.10f)
    doSomethingLucky();
}
```

Of course `0.10f` stands for 10% but you can adjust it. Like every PRNG algorithm this works by average usage. You won't get near to 10% unless `yourFunction()` is called a reasonable amount of times.

Comment: Because `nextFloat()` can result in zero, the comparison should be strictly less than. In other words, use `<` instead of `<=`. Of course, it would be a lot easier to reason correctly about the code if you used `nextInt(10)` instead of a `float`.

Comment: That's incorrect. It's just a wrong assumption, floats are not exact numbers so using a strict comparison in this situation won't change anything, also because the random sequence is generated from int values. I challenge you to provide a snippet that shows that using just < operator yields a more correct (near to 10%) result :)

Comment: Okay, I grant that in the specific case of 10%, the relation doesn't matter. But what about 50%? Or 75%? My point was that for general correctness, you should use `<` not `<=`.

Comment: @erickson: there's not going to be an appreciable difference between `<` and `<=` for comparing any float here. Let's take 50% for example. You're very rarely going to get _exactly_ `0.5f` out of `nextFloat()` since we're dealing with 32 random bits for the float. While it would be wrong to use `nextInt(10) <= 5` for 50% like you're getting at, the float case is much more like `nextInt(1000000000) <= 500000000`. It won't be statistically noticeable because you're rarely going to hit `500000000` for the equals in `<=` to matter.

Comment: I just tested it for fun over the whole range from 0.01 to 0.99 with 0.01 steps, 1000 tries each probability value with 1 million tosses and never got a difference. Probably if you use a chabce that can be fully expressed with a binary float could have a tiny chance of being different but not sure about it..

Comment: Thanks for unexplained -1s -.-

Comment: It seems like erickson is right here. while it doesn't make any appreciable difference in practicality, wouldn't it be better to use < simply because it's the more correct of the two operators (both of which will yield the same result distribution in reality)?

Comment: sorry man I edited a bit your code but I failed , if you like change it like I suggested.

Answer (score 35):

You just need something like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();

if (rand.nextInt(10) == 0) {
    System.out.println("you got lucky");
}
```

Here's a full example that measures it:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Rand10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int lucky = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            if (rand.nextInt(10) == 0) {
                lucky++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(lucky); // you'll get a number close to 100000
    }
}
```

If you want something like 34% you could use `rand.nextInt(100) < 34`.

Answer (score 3):

To take your code as a base, you could simply do it like that:

```java
if(Math.random() < 0.1){
  System.out.println("you got lucky");
}
```

FYI `Math.random()` uses a static instance of `Random`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Random](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). You may want to seed it, but the default is often sufficient.

```
Random random = new Random();
int nextInt = random.nextInt(10);
if (nextInt == 0) {
    // happens 10% of the time...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean getRandPercent(int percent) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextInt(100) <= percent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
public class MakeItXPercentOfTimes{

    public boolean returnBoolean(int x){
        if((int)(Math.random()*101) <= x){ 
            return true; //Returns true x percent of times.
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]pps){
        boolean x = returnBoolean(10); //Ten percent of times returns true.
        if(x){
            System.out.println("You got lucky");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is problematic, you should never cast the result of a call to `.random()` to an `int`, as you will introduce non-random biases.  Instead use the appropriate methods of `Random`, such as `.nextInt()` which handle those biases correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define "time" first, since 10% is a relative measure...

E.g. x is true every 5 seconds.

Or you could use a random number generator that samples uniformly from 1 to 10 and always do something if he samples a "1".

Answer (score 0):

You could always generate a random number (by default it is between 0 and 1 I believe) and check if it is <= .1, again this is not uniformly random....