# Performing functionality for a minimum of n% in x cases

Tags: java

Say I have a loop of 100 where every time I run it, 40% of the time I always have to do function A, 30% of the time I have to do function B and the remaining 30% I have to do C.

So far I have [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516917/java-do-something-x-percent-of-the-time) which doesn't exactly solve my problem as there is always the possibility of not performing the minimum amount required.

Is there something else I could use which could help me? Also these percentages have to calculated at runtime.

Comment: Is there any required order?

Comment: How so @ScaryWombat? And @TimBiegeleisen, the order is encouraged to be random.

Comment: Yes - you do a loop of 40 where you do A, then a loop of 30 where you do B, then a loop of 30 where you do C. That way you're guaranteed that you do everything at exactly the right percentages and it's clear what your code is doing.

Comment: So at the end of the 100 do you have to have exactly 40%, exactly 30% and exactly 30% of A, B, and C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a list containing 1 to 100, shuffle it, then use those values drawn sequentially to determine which function to execute:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i < 100; ++i) {
    list.add(i);
}
long seed = System.nanoTime();
Collections.shuffle(list, new Random(seed));

// now here is your loop
for (int i=0; i < 100; ++i) {
    if (list.get(i) < 40) {
        A();
    }
    else if (list.get(i) < 70) {
        B();
    }
    else {
        C();
    }
}
```