# Efficient way of handling percentile chance of event in programmatic way

Tags: android, node.js, logic

I am developing a small app like game, I have done this before and still not sure if it was the correct way to do it. What I need is percentile chance of some event, for example gaining an item after win 10% chance.

I have been using random number generator each time on server side, if number is <= 10 then user will gain reward, but it still does not satisfy 10% criteria across the all users environment.

I was thinking about recording user's turn number on server side and reward an item every nth time, but don't know if it's right way to do it. I would like to know about your ideas of doing it and suggestions. Also I did not know if stackoverflow is right place to post this or any other community of stackexchange group. If so please guide me in comment and I'll move question in appropriate community. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two completely different things that you mention in your question.  You have to decide which you want because a given algorithm cannot do both.

1. Every single time you try, there is a 10% chance.  You might see it hit two in a row and then it might not hit for 200 tries.  But, in the long run, it hits 10% of the time.
2. You are guaranteeing that out of every 10 tries, it will hit exactly once, never more, never less.

The first one above just fine with a proper random number pick and comparison.  But, you will get streaks of more hits than expected and fewer hits than expected.  Over time, the average number of hits will be your 10%.

```
function getRandomTenPercentOutcome() {
    return Math.random() < 0.1;
}
```

The second one requires a more complicated implementation that combines a random generator with keeping track of recent events.  The simplest way to implement a guaranteed 1 in 10 hit is to have the server create an filled with zeroes and then randomly select one cell in the array and change it to a 1.

Then, as you need to pick a random outcome, you `.shift()` off the first item in the array and use that value.  When the array becomes empty, you create a new one.  This forces exactly 1 in 10 outcomes (starting from the beginning) to hit.  Any given 10 outcomes might have 2 or 0 as you cross boundaries of creating a new array, but can't ever be further off than that.

You can make the array be either system-wide (one array for all users) or per-user (each user has their own outcome array).  If you want each user to perceive that it is very close to 1 in 10 for them personally, then you would need to make a separate outcome array for each user.

The length of the array can be adjusted to control how much variance you want to allow.  For example, you could create an array 50 long and randomly select 5 cells in the array.  That would allow more variability within the 50, though would still force 5 hits within the 50.

---

Both methods will average 10% in the long run.  The first may have greater deviations from 10% over any given interval, but will be much more random.  The second has much smaller deviations from 10% but some would say it is less random (which is not necessarily bad - depends upon your objective).  Both are "fair".

I know from my son's gaming that he perceives things to be "unfair" when a streak of unlikely things happen even though that streak is well within the occasionally expected results from a series of random events.  So, sometimes truly random may not seem as fair to a participant due to the occasionally sporadic nature of truly random.

Answer (score 3):

This questions seems to have been asked for multiple languages in other stackoverflow pages.

For example here it is for Java: [Java: do something x percent of the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516917/java-do-something-x-percent-of-the-time)

Check out the link for some ideas, but remember that it will tend to 10% of the time eventually given a large sample, you cant expect 10% immediately for just a couple of calls.

I do agree rewarding an item every nth time is not the way to go.

Comment: This is the correct answer. 10% is an average, not a guarantee.

Comment: Thanks for the direction though according to my calculations (well, I am not very good with probabilities) if we calculate 10% for each user, and consider 100 users, chance would be lowered, am I wrong here?

Comment: Having 100 users would just make the number of times you check for a prize higher but it will still be 10% chance for them to win. Considering a real time example could help clarify, for example if you have one person flip a coin and give them a prize if its head, the user has 50% chance of winning, if you now have 100 people and to each you tell them to flip a coin and give them a prize if it's heads, each of them will have 50% chance of winning, the only difference is there are more coins being flipped and more total prizes are probably being awarded, but its still 50% chance of winning each